# Declare module interface typescript and yarn workspaces

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using typescript and yarn workspaces. I have the following folder structure:

```
- UI Library (Exports React Components)
- Main App
```

The UI Library has a main index file that the main app will import from.

UI Library Main index.js:

```
export { default as Icon } from './Icon';
```

Then in the main app i import like so:

```
import { Icon } from 'ui-library';
```

**How can I declare the UI Library using typescript?**

I have tried the following, but I guess you can't import relative paths. In my ui lib I created a .d.ts file with something like

```
import { TIconProps } from "./Icon";

declare module 'ui-library' {
  export function Icon(props: TIconProps): React.ReactNode;
}
```

I get the error `Invalid module name in augmentation.`

Answer (score 0):

I can use `import("mod")` to access non-module scripts.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#import-types

Like this:

```js
declare module 'ui-library' {
  export const Icon: React.FC<import('./Icon').TIconProps>;
}
```