# Not extending library types with declare module when using yarn workspaces

Tags: typescript, yarn-workspaces

I am new to using yarn workspaces

I transferred all dependencies with the same versions as in the project without yarn workspaces

there is my structure:

[image]

there is an error:
[image]

Without using yarn workspaces the types are successfully extended, I have tried using the @types folder inside some-code-to-validate as originally without workspaces, but this does not help either

[image]

I also tried moving @vanilla-extract/css inside the overall package.json, this also failed

P.S. I found such a question, but it doesn't work for me [Declare module interface typescript and yarn workspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253113/declare-module-interface-typescript-and-yarn-workspaces)